# Cannot upload image from android app to jersey server

Tags: android, jersey

I am coding a function that encodes an image to Base64 string at android app and sends this string to a server for writing to a file. It can write a file but it just a part of the image. This is my code:

This code for get the list bit map of images:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mArrayUri.size(); i++) {
                lstBitmapImg.add(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mArrayUri.get(i)));
            }
```

The encode code here:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        System.out.println("Size=>>>>>>>>" + lstImgBitmap.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < lstImgBitmap.size(); i++) {

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            lstImgBitmap.get(i).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            builder.scheme("http")
                    .encodedAuthority("192.168.56.1:8080/HelloRESTful/rest")
                    .appendPath("image_service")
                    .appendPath("upload")
                    .appendPath(lstImgName.get(i))
                    .appendPath(encodedImage);
            String url = builder.build().toString();
            HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler();
            httpHandler.makeServiceCall(url, "POST");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the code to write into file:

```
@Path("/image_service")
public class ImageService {

    @Path("/upload/{imageName}/{encodeImage}")
    @POST
    public String uploadImage(@PathParam("imageName") String imgName, @PathParam("encodeImage") String encodeImage) {
        System.out.println(encodeImage);
        try {
            upload(imgName, encodeImage);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ImageService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return ex.toString();
        }
        return "Success";
    }

    public void upload(String imgName, String encodeImage) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedImage image;
        try (ByteArrayInputStream decodeBytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(encodeImage))) {
            image = ImageIO.read(decodeBytes);
        }

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Asus\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\HelloRESTful\\src\\main\\resources\\images\\" + imgName + ".jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
    }
}
```

And this is the result of the upload:

[[image: broken uploaded image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD9ld.jpg)

Comment: Converting the image to a String and putting it the URL is not a good idea. You should use Multipart. Have the endpoint accept multipart data format and send the request as a multipart request. You'll be able to send the file as a stream, which is the best way IMO. This is usually how files are sent, as it allows you to add file metadata to the request along with the file.

Comment: tks, I'll research about this